# How to push new data into firebase realtime database using cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I use a Cloud function to change realtime data in my firebase database every-time the function is called? I have a data cell called Points and I want to change the value of Points into a random number between 1 and 10 every time the function is deployed. I am really new to using firebase so I wouldn't know where to really start. I have looked most of the documentation provided but none of them helped. I have tried a few things but failed miserably. Please help

Thank you,

This is what I tried...

```
exports.userVerification = functions.database.ref('Points')

var ref = database().ref('Points')

var number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1)*10

ref.update(number)
```

Comment: You say you want the data to change when the cloud function is called, but the first line of the code you have there is from the example for calling a function when the data is changed -- exactly the opposite. You should start by [reading the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) for writing a function that is called via HTTP requests.

Comment: I want to use Pubsub instead of HTTP

Comment: In that case, [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) or [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub) should be a place to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) all the details on how to trigger a Cloud Function via Pub/Sub.

You will also find a very simple "Hello World" example in the official Cloud Functions sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/pubsub-helloworld

Your Cloud Function would then look like the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.randomNbr = functions.pubsub.topic('topic-name').onPublish((message) => {

      var ref = admin.database().ref();

      var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10)) + 1;

      return ref.update({ Points: number });

});
```

Note that we return the Promise returned by the `update()` asynchronous method, in order to indicate to the platform that the work is finished. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Note also that you cannot simply do `ref.update(number);`: you'll get an error (`Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.`)